# how to set video quality for ios 270 360 480 720 1080

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

To set video quality for ios.

I have tried to load m3u8 video url from server and i downloaded the m3u8 file & i segregate all RESOLUTION from video quality & AFTER SEGMENTS get the bandwidth of url in array.

When i load base url sample.m3u8 it has video & audio after that i set the base url of before segments and i have append the bandwidth url from array it was loading video as per quality selected but no audio came.

To achieve this i have made some solutions will work

I make separate to run original url which contains both video & audio and i run separately low bandwidth url which contains no audio to make sync

ex: `RESOLUTION=1280x720,SAMPLE_720p_v4.m3u8`

> SAMPLE.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-0",NAME="Default",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,URI="segments/SAMPLE_audio_v4.m3u8"

#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=30681000,CODECS="avc1.640028",URI="segments/SAMPLE_1080p_iframe.m3u8"

#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=30140000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f",URI="segments/SAMPLE_720p_iframe.m3u8"

#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=15431000,CODECS="avc1.42001f",URI="segments/SAMPLE_480p_iframe.m3u8"

#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=11009000,CODECS="avc1.42001e",URI="segments/SAMPLE_360p_iframe.m3u8"

#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=7850000,CODECS="avc1.420015",URI="segments/SAMPLE_270p_iframe.m3u8"


#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=4080000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-0"
```

> segments/SAMPLE_1080p_v4.m3u8

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3471000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-0"
```

> segments/SAMPLE_720p_v4.m3u8

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1934000,RESOLUTION=854x480,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-0"
```

> segments/SAMPLE_480p_v4.m3u8

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1106000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-0"
```

> segments/SAMPLE_360p_v4.m3u8

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=837000,RESOLUTION=480x270,CODECS="avc1.420015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-0"
```

> segments/SAMPLE_270p_v4.m3u8

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=185000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-0"
```

> segments/SAMPLE_audio_v4.m3u8

Comment: your ? is related to change the video quality or audio not playing.

Comment: yes , changing video quality audio not playing, for auto is working fine

Answer (score 2):

Use the preferredPeakBitRate property on your playeritem https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388541-preferredpeakbitrate you need to pass a valid bandwidth value.

Not sure why you are downloading the m3u8 file AVFoundation manage this for you.